# Difference between ionic and angular and ionic lifecycles

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lifecycle, subscription

I have a page that shows cities:
this page use a provider called "CitiesProvider"
Since these cities can change, i put u Subscription like:

```js
this.citiesSubscription = this.CitiesProvider.salesChanged
  .subscribe(
    (cities: City[]) => this.cities = cities
  )
```

Where is the perfect place to put the "unsubscribe" method between:
`ionViewWillLeave`

or `ionViewDidLeave`

or `ionViewWillUnload`
and what will go wrong if i put it in another?

And what's the difference  between using these (Ionic) lifecycle hocks or using

`ngOndestroy` from Anglar or any hocks coming from angular (since the ionic pages are also angular component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **ngOnDestroy** or **ionViewWillUnload** to unsubscribe from `Observables`.

The `ionViewDidLeave` and `ionViewWillLeave` hooks are getting fired every time you leave a page but don't indicate a page getting destroyed /removed from the dom.

**Example**:

If you use the `NavController` to push a page onto the stack the `ionViewDidLeave` but not the destroy hook is triggered because the page actually stays in the dom. If you navigate back the subscriptions are still assuring everything is up to date.

If you would unsubscribe while leaving the page you need to subscribe again in the `ionViewWillEnter` lifecycle hook.